# How can I change key of array with value of id on the javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, sparse-matrix

My javascript code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clubs = [ 
        {id: 3, name : 'chelsea'},
        {id: 6, name : 'city'},
        {id: 7, name : 'liverpool'},
        {id: 10, name : 'manchester united'},
        {id: 16, name : 'arsenal'}
    ];
    console.log(clubs)
</script>
```

I want to change the key of array to value of id

For example

key of `{id: 7, name : 'liverpool'},` is `2`

I want to change `2` to be `7`

Another example

key of `{id: 16, name : 'arsenal'}` is `4`

It to be `16`

How can I do it?

**Update** :

From the clubs array

index of `{id: 3, name : 'chelsea'}` is `0`

index of `{id: 6, name : 'city'}` is `1`

index of `{id: 7, name : 'liverpool'}` is `2`

index of `{id: 10, name : 'manchester united'}` is `3`

index of `{id: 16, name : 'arsenal'}` is `4`

I want to change it to be like this :

index of `{id: 3, name : 'chelsea'}` is `3`

index of `{id: 6, name : 'city'}` is `6`

index of `{id: 7, name : 'liverpool'}` is `7`

index of `{id: 10, name : 'manchester united'}` is `10`

index of `{id: 16, name : 'arsenal'}` is `16`

Comment: Not clear with the requirement. Can you please rephrase the problem

Comment: No. Well, yes, but you shouldn't. This would result in a wrong length of the array.

Comment: Would be better to use an object instead but your [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) is most likely to [find an object by id from the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects).

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: The only way you can do that is by reordering the array. Since if you change the location from one element. The keys of the other ones will be changed as well. You might be better off just rebuiding the array all together.

Comment: @nikhilagw I update my question

Comment: f.e. if you do `clubs[16] = {id: 16, name: 'arsenal'};` - then you have what you 'want', but `clubs.length` would then be 17... with only 5 objects in it.

Comment: @SuccessMan - And what about the missing id's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take `id` as index and create a sparse array.

```js
var clubs = [{ id: 3, name : 'chelsea' }, { id: 6, name : 'city' }, { id: 7, name : 'liverpool' }, { id: 10, name : 'manchester united' }, { id: 16, name : 'arsenal' }];
    
clubs = clubs.reduce((r, o) => (r[o.id] = o, r), []);
    
console.log(clubs);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What's the length of this array though? It may be surprising.

Comment: the length is the max id plus one.

Comment: @Nina Scholz The length to be `17`. Should only `5`

Comment: do you like to get an array or an object?

Comment: @Nina Scholz  I want to get an array

Comment: @SuccessMan You can't have an array of length 5 that has an element at position 16. That's not how arrays work.

Answer (score 3):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and create an object, instead of array, having id as key.

```js
var clubs = [ 
    {id: 3, name : 'chelsea'},
    {id: 6, name : 'city'},
    {id: 7, name : 'liverpool'},
    {id: 10, name : 'manchester united'},
    {id: 16, name : 'arsenal'}
];
var resData = clubs.reduce((a,x)=>{
 a[x.id] = x;
 return a;
},{})
console.log(resData)
```

Comment: This is the answer, either manually create the object or use a reducing function such as the example given here. The other answer of creating a sparse array would solve this but is bound to cause problems if you ever want to do anything other than look ups.

Comment: @Durga The length to be `3`. Should only `5`

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` like [Durga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771531/how-can-i-change-key-of-array-with-value-of-id-on-the-javascript#answer-49771635), but pass an object with a getter as `length` property.

```
var clubs = [ 
    {id: 3, name : 'chelsea'},
    {id: 6, name : 'city'},
    {id: 7, name : 'liverpool'},
    {id: 10, name : 'manchester united'},
    {id: 16, name : 'arsenal'}
];
var resData = {
    get length(){
        return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).filter(function(i){
            return /^\d+$/.test(i)
        }).length
    }
};
clubs.reduce(function(a,x){
    a[x.id] = x;
    return a;
},resData);
```